# How to keep my site error-free after chaning my site's URLS?

Tags: seo, htaccess, backlinks

My site is almost static. It has 64 pages. These pages before today were named with underscore. After checking my sites SEO with WooRank, the site advices me to change underscore links to dash links.

I did changed all my pages from using underscores to separate words in file name to dashes.

My site works 100% fine after the changes, I checked internal links.

But, what about the external links to my site?

What can I do to solve the issue that those links are linking to my underscore based URLs.

I did one thing in the .htaccess:
Redirect 301 for all my 60+ pages.

Comment: resubmit sitemap to major search engines and yes you can as .htacess for only underscore links..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did one thing in the .htaccess: Redirect 301 for all my 60+ pages.

That's all you need to do. Putting a 301 permanent on all renamed pages will handle both internal and external links.  Google will eventually re-crawl and use the new names.

This will keep your site free from errors but any change to the structure may result in a temporary dip in rank.  It it temporary and you will normally recover from it in a few weeks.

Comment: I lost some of my PR1 and PR2, is the .htaccess any help for the PR issue?

Comment: The .htaccess redirect is essential in trying to maintain PR. However, it does not necessarily pass on 100% of the PR, so there might be a dip initially. Changing the URL structure of a site is not without its costs.

Comment: Yep.  w3d is completely correct.  Apropos of nothing, you probably should have asked this question PRIOR to making the changes :)